# PyUSB: detect device unplug

Tags: python, linux, pyusb

I want my program to exit, whenever the device gets unplugged. 
My code:

```
device = usb.core.find(idVendor, idProduct)

device.detach_kernel_driver(0)

usb.util.claim_interface(device, 0)   
usb_cfg = device.get_active_configuration()
usb_interface = usb_cfg[(0,0)]
port_in = usb_interface[0]
port_out = usb_interface[1]

while True:
    # do read ....
```

How can I detect an unplug of the device.

Comment: use `libudev` (`pyudev` wrapper in case of `python`) for monitoring enumeration events. you only need `libusb` for actual device communication.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm as I looked over code on github, I would recomend to take code from this issue (I assume that You know what callbacks are :) )

[PYUSB Pull request- Hotplug](http://www.github.com/pyusb/pyusb/pull/160)

In this code you use **register_callback** with passed event **LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_LEFT**

> EDIT 5.12.2018 :

There is a link to hotplug branch at the forked repository of the pyusb :

https://github.com/roberthartung/pyusb/tree/hotplug

Comment: yes, i looked over the commit too. I thought there might be a simpler method.

Comment: you're link is pointing to a fork, the actual Issue/PR is here --> https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/pull/160